# Is there a modern term for "pessary cell"?

Tags: terminology, hematology, vitamin-b

I was reading about the vitamin B12, and came across [the description of a rare syndrome](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5131387/), with a mention of the "pessary cell" (a red blood cell in which the hemoglobin has disappeared from the center, leaving only the periphery visible). Judging by results of my literature search, this term is very rarely used. Is there a modern term for this appearance of red blood cells?

If there's no alternative term, why is it used so rarely in the literature? Because the phenomenon is rare, or because more advanced diagnostic methods came to be used, and it's no longer necessary to investigate the appearance of individual erythrocytes closely?

P.S. Further search led me to this article in Wikipedia, which contains descriptions of abnormally-formed erythrocytes, but still no "pessary cell": [poikilocytosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poikilocytosis).

> [image]

Comment: Um, I’ve always just called those cells “hypochromic”. I don’t know if they have an official name, but look at images for hypochromic RBCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @anongoodnurse that we typically refer to this as hypochromic.  Since you were looking up vitamin B12, then I am even more confident this is the case.  Vitamin B12 deficiency can cause a macrocytic, hypochromic anemia (see this article on [Diagnosis and Treatment of Macrocytic Anemias in Adults](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5689413/). This is how it is discussed in all of the pathophysiology textbooks I have taught from.  However, it does appear that the term pessary cell/corpuscle is an older term that is still used sometimes by pathology to refer to cells in severely anemic patients where the cells appear to have a ring of hemoglobin.

References

Nagao, T., & Hirokawa, M. (2017). Diagnosis and treatment of macrocytic anemias in adults. Journal of general and family medicine, 18(5), 200–204. https://doi.org/10.1002/jgf2.31